# Can I Use a Single CodeIgniter Model for Multiple Tables?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a database for a sports event that has multiple tables. Some of the tables hold the records for the Results, there is a User Profiles table, as well as a few Miscellaneous tables.

My Model is as follows:

```
class Results extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function displayrecords($table) {
        $query=$this->db->query("select * from " . $table);
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function getdisplayname($table) {
        $query=$this->db->query("select * from " . $table);
        return $query->result();
    }

    public function updatetable() {

    }

    public function deleterecords($table, $id) {
        $this->db->query("delete * from " . $table . " where id='" . $id . "'");
    }
}
```

And the Controller for the Index View:

```
public function index() {
    // Load the models
    $this->load->model('Results');
    $this->load->model('Info');
    $this->load->model('TableNames');

    // Create the array to store the data for the index page
    $data['results'] = array();

    // Get a list of all the tables in the event database
    $tables = $this->db->list_tables();
    $data['tables'] = array();

    // Loop through the list of table names and extract the results tables
    foreach($tables as $table) {
        if (strpos($table, "rs_") === 0) {
            array_push($data['tables'], $table);
            $temp = $this->Results->displayrecords($table);
            array_push($data['results'], $temp);
            $data['headnames'] = $this->db->list_fields($table);
        }
    }

    // Get the event info data and the list of Human Readable Table Names
    $data['tablenames'] = $this->TableNames->getnames();
    $data['eventinfo'] = $this->Info->getinfo();

    // Render the templates
    $this->parser->parse('templates/index_header', $data);
    $this->parser->parse('pages/index', $data);
    $this->parser->parse('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is if it is advisable to use a single CodeIgniter Model, with all of the Results tables. An example of the Results tables: Top Ten Male 30 to 39 Years for the 21KM event and Top Ten Males 40 to 49 years also for the 21KM event. I currently have all of the Results tables using the same Models methods such as:

```
public function displayrecords($table) {
    $query=$this->db->query("select * from " . $table);
    return $query->result();
}
```

which takes a result table as the parameter, and displays the Results. I would create Models for each of the Results tables, but I do not know before hand what name the table will have, columns it will have etc. Each Results table is created through a webpage by an Administrator, and added to the database as needed. Each table will have the same operations performed on them, delete rows, update row. That is why i thought it would be best to have one Model that can work with all the tables.

I am not sure if the way I am going about this is correct though as I seem to already be having a few problems. When trying to delete a record from a table for example, I can get the id of the row that would need to be deleted, but I am not sure how to get the database table name as the deleterecords method would need 2 parameters, $id, and $tablename to delete the record correctly. The model method is as such:

```
public function deleterecords($tablename, $id) {
    $this->db->query("delete from " . $tablename . " where id='" . $id . "'");
}
```

and then in the view I am displaying each results table:

```
foreach ($table as $row) {
    echo "<tr id='result_" . $row->id . "'>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Place . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='bibcell'>" . $row->BibNumber . "<a class='editbut' href=''><img class='bibnum' src='" . base_url() . "assets/images/editicon.png' width='80' style='padding-left: 20px;'></a><a class='delbut' href='deletedata?id=" . $row->id . "'><img src='" . base_url() . "assets/images/deleteicon.png' width='75' style='padding-left: 5px;'></a></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Name . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Age . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Club . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row->Time . "</td>";
    echo "<td><select class='user-options'><option value='pending' style='background: red;'>Pending</option><option value='checked' style='background: green;'>Checked</option></select></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Would using a hidden input be the way to get the table name is there possibly features within CodeIgniter that would handle using multiple tables with a single Model?

EDIT:

I have managed to figure out this:

```
echo "<td class='bibcell'>" . $row->BibNumber . "<a class='editbut' href=''><img class='bibnum' src='" . base_url() . "assets/images/editicon.png' width='80' style='padding-left: 20px;'></a><a class='delbut' href='deletedata?id=" . $row->id . "&tablename=" . $tables[$i] . "'><img src='" . base_url() . "assets/images/deleteicon.png' width='75' style='padding-left: 5px;'></a></td>";
```

to pass the id and tablename to the Model method to be deleted, but I am getting undefined variable tablename. I can see the tablename variable is in the url though.

```
http://localhost/results/pages/deletedata?id=1&tablename=rs_toptenfemale
```

Comment: almost a year ago, have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your case, but you can use multiple functions in your model and you can handle all the table in a single model (but I think it's not advisable and good practice )

You can use dynamic functions like this to avoid too much of functions in model

```
<?php 

if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Common_model extends CI_Model {

  
public function insertContent($data,$table){
    $this->db->insert($table,$data);    
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0)
    {
        return TRUE; 
    }
    else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function updateContent($data,$table,$whereField,$value){

    $this->db->where($whereField,$value);
    $update=$this->db->update($table, $data);
    if ($update > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function login_check($data,$table)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where($data);
    $query=$this->db->get($table);
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return TRUE;         
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function retriveTableDetails($table)
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}

public function retriveTableDetailsById($table,$id)
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $query=$this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use below code for handle operations in common model.
```

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Users_model extends CI_Model 
{
  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }

  //get data with whare condition OR without where condition EX: get_where() OR get()
  function select_where($table,$where='',$limit='',$offset='')
  {
    if ($where!=="")
    {
      return $this->db->get_where($table,$where,$limit,$offset)->result();
    }
    else
    {
      return $this->db->get($table,$limit,$offset)->result(); 
    }
  }    

  //count data with whare condition OR without where condition  
  function select_count($table,$where='')
  {
    if ($where!=="")
    {
      $this->db->select('*')->from($table)->where($where); 
      $q = $this->db->get(); 
      return $q->num_rows();
    }
    else
    {
      $this->db->select('*')->from($table); 
      $q = $this->db->get(); 
      return $q->num_rows();
    }
  }

  //Insert Data
  public function insert_data($table,$data)
  {
    return $this->db->insert($table,$data);
  }
  
  //update data with whare condition OR without where condition
  public function update_data($table,$datak,$edit)
  {
    $field=$this->db->field_data($table);
    $tid=$field[0]->name;
    $data=array(
      $tid=>$edit); 
    $this->db->where($data); 
    $res=$this->db->update($table,$datak);
    if($res)
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  }  
  public function delete_where($table,$data)
  {
    if($this->db->delete($table,$data))
    {
      return true;
    }
    else
    {
      return false;
    }
  } 



}
```